# Add a button to the top of a listView dynamically

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I am displaying a listView on my ListViewActivity. And I would like to add a button to the top  of the LisView. I have tried this:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //....
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_singlegrey);
    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_comment);
    Button btAddComment = new Button(this);
    btAddComment.setText("Añadir comentario");
    linear.addView(btAddComment);
    setContentView(linear); 
    //....      
}
```

The file listview_singlegrey.xml is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/list_comment"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp" android:background="@drawable/fondomain">    
    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:divider="@layout/linedivider" android:dividerHeight="10px"
          android:cacheColorHint="#0000" android:paddingTop="10dp"           
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

But I cant see the button. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add button to the top of your listview, you must add that to zero'th index

```
linear.addView(btAddComment, 0);
```

Now your listview is in index 1.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of

```
setContentView(linear);
```

Also, try adding the button in XML first and make sure it shows up. You may need to fiddle with `layout_height` and `layout_weight` parameters so the ListView doesn't push it offscreen. Once you know the right parameters, set them at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this method [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) which adds a fixed view to appear at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you miss the LayoutParams for the button when you create it in code.
Use Button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(...)).

But i dont recommend this way. Why dont you just add the button above your listview
in the XML? Then it stays fixed there. Like this:

```
<LinearLayout> <Button/> <ListView /> </LinearLayout>
```

If you want a "scrollable button", which scrolls with the listview,
write a XML file with the button, inflate it via getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout. ..) and use ListView.addHeaderView().

Comment: I dont want to fix a button on the layout, as i use it in others ListActivities which dont need it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use the  [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) of `ListView`.

**According to the documentation**

> Add a fixed view to appear at the top
>   of the list. If addHeaderView is
>   called more than once, the views will
>   appear in the order they were added.
>   Views added using this call can take
>   focus if they want. NOTE: Call this
>   before calling setAdapter. This is so
>   ListView can wrap the supplied cursor
>   with one that will also account for
>   header and footer views.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a header for listview? you can use header like this

```
listView.addHeaderView(view);
```

Here view may be any view component.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the layout parameters before adding the button to the layout.

Something like this:

```
btAddComment.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

That should do the trick. If not, let me know.